# How to correctly setup Django Rest Framework social login and register, alongside local auth with jwt

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have to create API endpoints for user login and registration with facebook, twitter and local auth. I also want to connect social accounts with local one. Have used django-rest-auth and different packages and most of them are garbage. For example, django-rest-auth has issues with custom login serializers etc. How should it be done without writing messy code and without use of "bugfull" packages?

Answer (score 3):

I use

django-rest-auth

django-allauth

and drf's local tokenAuth. Here is a good guide https://medium.com/@gabriel_gamil/react-native-expo-django-facebook-authentication-sign-in-83625c49da7

Good luck!